# How to reloadData?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, reloaddata

I am not dumb and I know how to reload data. I am in a tricky situation where I have a UIView inside another UIView both named OHGridView. I have to keep them named the same way.

With the OHGridView example code, the refresh looked a little like this:

```
[(OHGridView *)self.view reloadData];
```

But now that I added a UIView, it no longer works.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**

```
Code removed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSNotificationCenter may be what you need. You can register for events (eg a perform update event) and then post these events from anywhere. These go to the notification center and then to your class/view. When the event is received, you just do what is needed.

The docs are here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Inside the OHGridView you would call during initialization:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReloadNotification:) name:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:nil];
```

Then, just define the method:

```
- (void)ReloadNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self reloadData];
}
```

So, when you want an update to occur, you then just call:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:self];
```

When you deallocate the OHGridView you should remove the observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however that doesn't really answer my question. I just need a simple method that will refresh my OHGridView.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your problem is, but my thought was that perhaps the wrong OHGridView is getting updated. Using the NSNotificationCenter you don't have to worry about where a view is; you just send it an updated message directly.

Comment: Thanks for the code, however it doesn't work. I called it every 5 seconds with a NSTimer and nothing happened even after I deleted something from it.

Comment: Did you try printing something in the notification to be sure it was getting called?

Comment: The addObserver call can go in viewWillAppear. Once that's getting called you should start receiving the messages. I use this in multiple places in my code.

Comment: One more thing, if I wanted to call it from a different class, what would it look like? I've tried this and nothing happens: ` DetailViewController *theDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeatilViewController.xib" bundle:nil]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:self];` I've also tried running the action in my DetailViewController like this: ` DetailViewController *theDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DeatilViewController.xib" bundle:nil]; [theDetail reloadTheData];` and I have yet to see success.

Comment: You can call the postNotification from anywhere and it should get to your OHGridView, as long as the OHGridView has already registered. It's probably not working in your examples because the view has been loaded, but hasn't appeared yet. I would just add the reload data call to viewWillAppear and then use the notification center for further updates.

Comment: I have it in my viewWillAppear. I've updated my post - I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: viewWillAppear isn't called until the view is added to another view or otherwise presented to the user. So, just call [self reloadData]; from viewWillAppear, and then the notification will handle any subsequent reload requests.

Comment: In my case, the OHGridView appears before it will call anything, that's just how it's set up. I put `[self reloadData];` in, and still it's not reloading.

Comment: I couldn't help more without looking at the code. But, it might help to use [self -performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:].